# fetch values from object using loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object, for-loop

I have an object that i got after printing $header

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($header);
echo "</pre>";


stdClass Object
(
    [date] =>
    [Subject] =>
    [message_id] => 
    [toaddress] =>
    [to] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [personal] => A1
                    [mailbox] => B1
                    [host] => C1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [personal] => A2
                    [mailbox] => B2
                    [host] => C2
                )
        )
)
```

I wish to fetch values from this object. I got the outer values using below format

```
$subject = $header->Subject;
```

for the inner values i used this code

```
$to1 = $header->to[0]->personal;
$to2 = $header->to[1]->personal;
```

I got the required result, but i would like to use a loop for values inside `[to]`  as the number of index values can varry inside it.

can anyone tell how can i do so

Comment: `foreach($header->to as $item) $item->personal....`

Comment: It's an array, you loop over it just like any other array. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 foreach($header->to as $key => $val)
 {
   $result[] = $val->personal;
 }
 print_r($result);
```